# Selected nodes and save status checkboxes to datatables child rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I create myself tables with drop-down slider for each record in DataTables. More or less something like:
[`example`](http://jsfiddle.net/ds3qp41g/25/)
I have several problems with this:.
1) how simply select all sub-elements of one record?
2) When Collapse slider, checkbox status is not remembered?

Ultimately, it will be a list of parameters. When a customer mark what he wants. ID will be sent to WebService.